Error in dynamically allocating memory for a 2D array
I am dynamically allocating a 2D array based on user input for the number of rows and columns, but I encounter a memory access violation when trying to assign values to the maze[i] in the code. Here's the relevant part of my code.Could anyone help me?
I dynamically allocated memory for a 2D array in C
int main() {

    int m, n;
    
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    

    int** maze = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * (m + 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++) {
        maze[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 2));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 2; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == m + 1 || j == 0 || j == n + 1)maze[i][j] = 1;//1代表障碍
            else {
                if (j == n)scanf("%d\n", &maze[i][j]);
                else scanf("%d", &maze[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 2; j++) {
            
                if (j == n)printf("%d\n", maze[i][j]);
                else printf("%d ", maze[i][j]);
            
        }
    }
}


At which line does it crash according to your debugger and what are the values of m,n,i,j at that point?

It is not an 2D array only an array of pointers.

Using a trailing white-space like "%d\n" as a format string for scanf is usually not doing what you expect, and is almost never needed. You don't need that if (j == n) check.

@Lundin:THanks for your reply! This question's setting is how to find a way out of a maze. And m,n,i,j stand for the maze matrix 's rows ,columns. I've edit this twice according a kind bro 's advice, in a bid to make it convenient to read, which results in the loss of the previous photo that emcompass the crash line information. l could say it's line6  :maze[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 2)).

@ 0___________: YES bro, but my visual studio seems not to support VLA when l encode:int (*maze) [m][n]. So l have to use function malloc to realize it.

@ Some programmer dude: Your advice is unbelievably correct! l've correct it by your wisdom. It does help a lot and now l can input a 2d matrix smoothly!


Always check the result of malloc
Always check the result of scanf
Use meaningful variable names. Avoid n,m,i,j
Use printfs or assertions when you try to debug your code.
Use objects, not types in sizeof
Comment your code.
Clean all the rubbish behind (use free)
Generally - do not be lazy when programming

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int totalRows, totalCols;
    int** maze = NULL; // Pointer to the maze
    int exitCode = EXIT_SUCCESS; // Single exit point
    int row;

    // Prompt user for the size of the maze
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    if (scanf("%d,%d", &totalRows, &totalCols) != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input for rows and columns.\n");
        exitCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Allocate memory for the maze (array of row pointers) using calloc
    maze = calloc(totalRows + 2, sizeof(*maze));
    if (maze == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for maze rows.\n");
        exitCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Allocate memory for each row
    for (row = 0; row < totalRows + 2; row++)
    {
        maze[row] = malloc(sizeof(*maze[row]) * (totalCols + 2));
        if (maze[row] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for maze columns at row %d.\n", row);
            exitCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    // Input maze data
    printf("Enter the maze data (without boundaries, row by row):\n");
    for (row = 0; row < totalRows + 2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < totalCols + 2; col++)
        {
            // Set boundary cells
            if (row == 0 || row == totalRows + 2 - 1 || col == 0 || col == totalCols + 2 - 1)
            {
                maze[row][col] = 1; // 1 represents a barrier
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate access within non-boundary regions
                assert(row > 0 && row <= totalRows);
                assert(col > 0 && col <= totalCols);

                // Read input for non-boundary cells
                if (col == totalCols)
                {
                    if (scanf("%d", &maze[row][col]) != 1)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input for maze cell at row %d, col %d.\n", row, col);
                        exitCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
                        goto cleanup;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (scanf("%d", &maze[row][col]) != 1)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input for maze cell at row %d, col %d.\n", row, col);
                        exitCode = EXIT_FAILURE;
                        goto cleanup;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the maze layout
    printf("Maze layout with boundaries:\n");
    for (row = 0; row < totalRows + 2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < totalCols + 2; col++)
        {
            // Validate access within extended boundaries
            assert(row >= 0 && row < totalRows + 2);
            assert(col >= 0 && col < totalCols + 2);

            // Print maze layout
            if (col == totalCols + 2 - 1)
            {
                printf("%d\n", maze[row][col]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d ", maze[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

cleanup:
    // Free allocated memory
    if (maze != NULL)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < totalRows + 2; row++)
        {
            free(maze[row]);
        }
        free(maze);
    }

    return exitCode;
}


I did not check the logic of your program - only added assertions and did general cleanup.

l can't appreciate more for your meticulous and patient suggestions. lt's wise of you to discern my dumb errors and bad habits. As a beginner, l do think your advice to-the-point and helpful. l 'll try to foster a better habit under your advice. Last but not least, thans again for your answers and kindness.! My English is poor , and l'm very sorry to reply so late.
